# Difference between TransactionScope and Rollback Transaction manually?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm working on a project which was developed by others before. In the program, it does something like this:

```
 reportConnection = new SqlConnection(sConnStr);
 reportConnection.Open();
 try
 {
     using (SqlTransaction trans = reportConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))                    

     {
        ......
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, reportConnection, trans))
        {
            ....
        }
        trans.Commit();
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger ....
}
fianlly
{
    if (reportConnection != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)reportConnection).Dispose();
    }

}
```

The problem I can see is that it does not rollback the transaction if there is an error in the using block. So, here is **the 1st question**: If there is an error, the trans will not be commit (no rollback either), but the connection will be disposed (the trans will not be disposed). In this case, what side effect it will create? Will it create an orphan connection/transaction, which is open? Thus, will create deadlock?

I did some search, it seems preferred way to do this is using transactionscope (**below code from microsoft**):

```
try
{
    // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing 
    // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work. 
    using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
        {
            // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the  
            // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
            connection1.Open();

            // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
            SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
            returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

            // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting 
            // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you 
            // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened 
            // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.    
            using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
            {
                // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed 
                // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                connection2.Open();

                // Execute the second command in the second database.
                returnValue = 0;
                SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
            }
        }

        // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown, 
        // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
        scope.Complete();

    }

}
catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
catch (ApplicationException ex)
{
    writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

**My 2nd question** is: what if I did it manually like below. Any advantages using transactionscope? Are they literally the same?

```
reportConnection = new SqlConnection(sConnStr);
reportConnection.Open();
try
 {
     using (SqlTransaction trans = reportConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted))                    

     {
        try
        {
            ......
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, reportConnection, trans))
            {
                ....
            }
            trans.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            try
            {
                // incase rollback has error
                trans.Rollback();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger ....
}
fianlly
{
    if (reportConnection != null)
    {
        ((IDisposable)reportConnection).Dispose();
    }

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the `SqlTransaction` documentation:

> Dispose should rollback the transaction. However, the behavior of
>   Dispose is provider specific, and should not replace calling Rollback.

Taken from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf2cw321.aspx

I guess it all depends how paranoid you are about trying to force broken implementations to work properly when you think they might not.  The first code sample is definitely the simplest and it's only going to fail if your provider isn't working as it should.

EDIT complexity example - Should your last snippet be:

```
try { /*...*/ 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, reportConnection, trans)) {
        /*...*/ }
    trans.Commit();
} catch { try { trans.Rollback(); } catch {} throw; }
```

or

```
try { /*...*/ 
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sSQL, reportConnection, trans)) {
        /*...*/ }
} catch { try { trans.Rollback(); } catch {} throw; }
trans.Commit();
```

?